# How to determine if a particular route/path needs authorization/authentication?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a Middlere, and I want it NOT to run when the path doesn't need authentication. Is it possible to know this in ASP.NET Core in a simple way? (Without having to read the attributes of the controller functions by introspection)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried integrating into the authentication framework? You register your Auth middleware and then the framework deals with the controller attributes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the public Task Invoke method of the middleware,  you could always just do a check of whether or not to advance to the next level in the pipeline.

For example,

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{

    // If the request path doesn't match, skip
    if (!context.Request.Path.Equals(_options.Path, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        return _next(context);
    }
}
```

The return_next(context) just skips this middleware entirely to the next stage of the pipeline.  You can put custom logic here depending on what you are trying to do.